How to find the highest value count row in pyspark?
I have this dateframe



type
ptype
time
length
bins
count




BC
1
2023-07-02 18:07:28
8283
CB
1


BC
1
2023-07-12 16:55:45
3402
7.2
3331


BC
1
2023-07-02 18:07:28
8283
7.2
8209


BC
1
2023-07-19 21:51:02
9671
3.3
1


BC
1
2023-07-02 18:07:28
8283
3.3
1


BC
1
2023-07-08 01:32:12
9642
CB
17


BC
1
2023-07-19 21:51:02
9671
CB
47


BC
1
2023-07-19 21:51:02
9671
7.2
9611


BC
1
2023-07-08 01:32:12
9642
7.2
9613



For each group which is grouped at (type, ptype,time,length) i want the value of bins which has the highest value_count
so the expected output will be the following



type
ptype
time
length
bins
count




BC
1
2023-07-02 18:07:28
8283
7.2
8209


BC
1
2023-07-08 01:32:12
9642
7.2
9613


BC
1
2023-07-12 16:55:45
3402
7.2
3331


BC
1
2023-07-19 21:51:02
9671
7.2
9611



As for each group column bins value 7.2 is the highest.
Please help.
I tried the following code but not getting the correct result, it produces different result at each run
df.groupBy('type', 'ptype', 'time', 'length', 'bins') \
        .count() \
        .orderBy( 'type', 'ptype', 'time', 'length', desc('count')) \
        .groupBy( 'type', 'ptype', 'time', 'length') \
        .agg(first('bins').alias('bins')).show()


df = (df.groupBy('type', 'ptype', 'time', 'length', 'bins').count().orderBy( 'type', 'ptype', 'time', 'length', desc('count')).first())
Simply use "first"

The above comment should end in nlog(n) complexity. I would say Not fast enough for large datasets.

You can simply achieve that with a window function and a post filtering.
import datetime as dt
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql import Row, Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 2, 18, 7, 28),
        length=8283,
        bins="CB",
        count=1
    ),
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 12, 16, 55, 45),
        length=3402,
        bins="7.2",
        count=3331
    ),
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 2, 18, 7, 28),
        length=8283,
        bins="7.2",
        count=8209
    ),
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 19, 21, 51, 2),
        length=9671,
        bins="3.3",
        count=1
    ),
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 2, 18, 7, 28),
        length=8283,
        bins="3.3",
        count=1
    ),
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 8, 1, 32, 12),
        length=9642,
        bins="CB",
        count=17
    ),
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 19, 21, 51, 2),
        length=9671,
        bins="CB",
        count=47
    ),
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 19, 21, 51, 2),
        length=9671,
        bins="7.2",
        count=9611
    ),
    Row(
        type="BC",
        ptype=1,
        time=dt.datetime(2023, 7, 8, 1, 32, 12),
        length=9642,
        bins="7.2",
        count=9613
    )
]


schema = StructType([
    StructField(name="type", dataType=StringType()),
    StructField(name="ptype", dataType=IntegerType()),
    StructField(name="time", dataType=TimestampType()),
    StructField(name="length", dataType=IntegerType()),
    StructField(name="bin", dataType=StringType()),
    StructField(name="count", dataType=IntegerType()),
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

df_new = (
    df
    .withColumn(
        "max_count", 
        f.max("count").over(
            Window.partitionBy("type", "ptype", "time", "length")
        )
    )
    .filter("max_count = count")
    .drop("max_count")
)

df_new.display()





Starting from the dataframe given in the question (including the column count) you can group the data by type, ptype, time and length and then use the aggregations functions

max for the count column and
max_by for the bins column

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy('type', 'ptype', 'time', 'length') \
    .agg(F.max("count"), F.max_by("bins", "count")) \
    .show()

Result:
+----+-----+-------------------+------+----------+-------------------+
|type|ptype|               time|length|max(count)|max_by(bins, count)|
+----+-----+-------------------+------+----------+-------------------+
|  BC|    1|2023-07-02 18:07:28|  8283|      8209|                7.2|
|  BC|    1|2023-07-08 01:32:12|  9642|      9613|                7.2|
|  BC|    1|2023-07-12 16:55:45|  3402|      3331|                7.2|
|  BC|    1|2023-07-19 21:51:02|  9671|      9611|                7.2|
+----+-----+-------------------+------+----------+-------------------+

